# How to query array which is present as string in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table called `table` with column called `column` with datatype `text` with values like '`["1","2"]`'.

I need to get all records which has "1" as one of the element.

```
select * 
from table 
where column.....?
```

How should the where clause be?

Comment: `where column like '%"1"%'`

Comment: no... the number can range upto 300. I dont want results with 10,100,101,201....

Comment: Thanks to the double quotes that will not happen.

Comment: Oh really? so converting the string to array type and then checking with contains operator is an overkill huh?

Comment: @404 yes you are right. The dataype is `text` have updated the question.

Comment: Place the `CREATE TABLE` structure aswell as your comment made it a "performance" question aswell.. And ideally also some records with example data -> [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @RaymondNijland The table is huge and complicated, actually the and the details of the other columns aren't necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `LIKE`. Keep the double quotes to pass 1, but avoid other numbers containing that digit.

```
select * 
from table 
where column like '%"1"%'
```

Comment: Hey can you also post in any postgres doc that says about double quotes. It will be helpful

Comment: That's just how LIKE works. The `%` wild-card stands for any sequence of zero or more characters. In your case look for something that has zero or some arbitrary characters, then `"1"`, and then zero or some arbitrary characters. http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-like/

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`?`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html) operator on `jsonb` type:

```
select *
from (
    select '["1","2"]' union all
    select '["0"]'
) as a(data)
where
    a.data::jsonb ? '1'
```

In general, I'd consider storing your data as `jsonb` instead of string.

[`db<>fiddle example`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=fedc19b7b8fdeca4625fe52ce0015763)